# Second countability of Minkowski double cones.

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, special-relativity

In the 4-dimensional Minkowski spacetime, for a given point $x=(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$, its timelike future or past set is defined as,
$I^{\pm}(x)= \{y=(y^0,y^1,y^2,y^3) \in \mathbb{R}^4: \eta_{\mu \nu}(y−x)^{\mu} (y−x)^{\nu}>0,\pm (y^0−x^0)>0 \}$
where $(\eta_{\mu \nu})=diag(1,−1,−1,−1)$, and one also defines the double cone sets as $\mathcal{O}(x,y)=I^+(x) \cap I^-(y)$.

I have to show that there is a countable family $ \{\mathcal{O}_n \}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, of double cones in $\mathbb{R}^4$ so that every open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as a union of suitable elements of $\{\mathcal{O}_n\}$.

I know I have to use the second countability property, but I am not certain of how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: What you have to show is false (assuming that you are using the standard topology on $R^4$). Where did this problem come from?

Comment: It is the last part of a problem in my quantum field theory in curved spacetime class. The problem follows the Euclidean metric induced topology on $\mathbb{R}^4$, that was shown in our lectures. I have already shown that $I^{\pm}(x)$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^4$, as well as that $\mathcal{O}(x,y)$ is open and non-empty. This is the part of the problem I'm stuck at. Why do you say that the claim of the problem is false?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I misread the question: Did not notice the intersection part. A hint is to first work out this problem in the case of $R^{1,1}$ where you can see what these subsets look like.